# Why this insert query is not working?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>User Registration</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!--Design area-->
    <a href="register.php">Register</a><=====><a href="login.php">Login</a>
    <h3>Registration Form</h3>
    <form action=""  method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
    </form>

<!--End design area-->
<!--PHP Section-->
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','log') or die("Connection failure");
    $query="SELECT * FROM log_data WHERE username='".$username."'";//Validation query
    $run_query=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $row_count=mysqli_num_rows($run_query);
```

Till now everything is working. But when I gave the row count condition and then write insert query, at that time browser says account not created. That means my query is not running. Why?

```
if($row_count==0){
        $query="INSERT INTO log_data(username,password) VALUES('$username','$password')";//insert query
        $run_query=mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if($run_query){//if inserted
    echo "Account Successfully Created";
    } else {
    echo "Account not created";
    }

}else{
    echo "This username already exits";
}
}

 ?>
 <!--End Php Section-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY). Also, storing passwords as plain-text string is a terrible idea.

Comment: mysqli_num_rows($query);

Comment: $row_count = $query->num_rows;

Comment: paste the `$query="INSERT INTO log_data(username,password) VALUES('$username','$password')";//insert query
        $run_query=mysqli_query($con,$query)  or die(mysqli_error($con));` & check the output

Comment: it's terrible Idea to use `die()` in production, it provides the information to potential hackers about your code or DB.

Comment: You are right. But This is educational purpose.Only me.Thanks for your suggestion. @teresko

Answer (score -1):

You may want to take some precautions to prevent SQL injection here, this code is vulnerable as it stands.

```
$stmt = mysqli->prepare("SELECT col1 FROM t1 WHERE col2 = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);

$stmt->execute();
```

This should help, make sure you use the '?' Placeholder for any user defined input variables.

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
<?php 

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","log");
// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


if(isset($_POST['register'])){

    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $query="SELECT * FROM log_data WHERE username='".$username."'"; //Validation query


    if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$query)){

    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    //$row_count = $query->num_rows;

    if($rowcount==0){

        $sql="INSERT INTO log_data(username,password) VALUES('$username','$password')"; //insert query

        $run_query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        if($run_query){  //if inserted

           echo "Account Successfully Created";
         } 

         else {

         echo "Account not created";

         }

     }
     else{

     echo "This username already exits";

     }
}

}

?>
```